# Jobs Overlapping In Laravel

Tags: laravel

I was reading the Laravel Docs at [Job Overlap Section](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queues#preventing-job-overlaps). But I don't get it how the jobs can overlap. If I am right, Jobs are processed one by one. Then there is no reason for them to overlap.

According to docs:

> This can be helpful when a queued job is modifying a resource that should only be modified by one job at a time

My concept about it is not that clear yet, so any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The jobs sit in a queue,

Example. Job1, Job2, Job3, Job4, Job5

If you have 1 worker consuming the queue, then your jobs will never overlap

Job1 would have to be completed before it can start Job2

If you have more than 1 worker, say you have 3 workers consuming the queue
then Job1, Job2, Job3 will all be processed at the same time.

This is when overlap can occur.

Comment: Got it. This multiple workers thing is the whole point. Thanks